# Why does my shell open many instances of itself?

Tags: command-line, bash

I've been messing with the `chsh` command so that I could change the name displayed in my shell before each command is issued, for example `picard@ubuntu:$`. My problem arose when I gave the command `chsh -s /bin/ksh picard`, not fully knowing what the results would be. Among this command, I also used `grep ksh /etc/shells/`. Now, any time I try to open a terminal, be it bash, dash, sh or urxvt, it either just doesn't open or starts spawning instances of urxvt until it has so many open, the computer hangs and then the instances are all closed.

What exactly did I screw up? I really would prefer not having to reinstall, but I can't use Linux without a command line, which I'm sure you guys can sympathize with.

Comment: what is your default shell? bash. if so did you add urxvt to $HOME/.bashrc?

Comment: My default shell is(was) urxvt. Now, I can't even get a shell open. I will try what you suggested and report back.

Comment: That is the problem. urxvt is recursively calling its self over and over again. use ctrl+alt+F2 and log in as root and change your default shell.

Comment: No dice, sir. Surely there must be some way to reverse this behavior.

Comment: I used chsh -s to change the shell, however I didn't know what to put after the command so it was mostly guesswork. After I rebooted, this situation happened. How do I change my default shell?

Comment: I'm attempting to use ctrl+alt+F2, and it does bring up a terminal. However, after I log in, it doesn't give me a prompt to issue commands, only a blank cursor where you can type literally anything. Any ideas?

Comment: are you logging in as root?

Comment: It doesn't accept my root login as valid. It does accept picard, however.

Comment: log into recovery mode get a root shell. and run chsh -s /bin/bash picard . see qbi's answer for the overall issue.

Comment: Funny you post this, as I just did it. I've entered the command, but now its returning "chsh: PAM authentication failed". Thanks for the help so far by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `chsh` has nothing to do with changing your prompt. As the [manpage of chsh(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chsh) writes, it's purpose is to change your login shell. So at the moment `ksh` is your login shell. If you want to change that, simply enter

```
chsh -s /bin/bash picard
```

This makes `bash` your login shell. Usually this is the default at Ubuntu.

You can also open a terminal with the command `urxvt -e /bin/bash` or just `urxvt -e bash`. When you open a terminal without using the `-e` option, your system will start `ksh`. By default `ksh` only uses `$` as prompt. So thatswhy you see no fancy `user@system` prompt.

However another way to change back your login shell is to edit `/etc/passwd`. Open the file with your favorite editor like:

```
sudo vim /etc/passwd #or
sudo nano /etc/passwd #or
gksudo gedit /etc/passwd
```

and move to the line with your user name. At the end of the line you'll find `/bin/ksh`. Change it to `/bin/bash`, save the file and log in again. Now you should have your usual shell back.

If you want to change your prompt, enter `echo $PS1` to see actual settings. The bash manpage tells you what to change to have a nice prompt.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you have any idea why the terminal wouldn't be accepting my root login? It says the password is invalid, which I know is not true.